# copy library item Id to root list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, workflow

I have a library on SharePoint 2010 site with some items in it. 
I copied a single item Id to another list using a workflow.

Now I want to copy multiple library Item ID in one go to the root list. How can I configure my workflow to concatenate the ID from those multiple items and store the resulting value to one column(Major ID column) in the root list.

Answer (score 0):

If you just copy the item ID in different document libraries to a library custom ID column, you can create a workflow in the relevant library, and add “Create a list item” action to create an item, then  add relevant column in the Create New List Item dialog as below:
[image]